# Not getting the right time in apex

Tags: apex, datetime

DateTime.now() return time stamp which is 10 hours more than the current time, I am currently using the Hawaii standard time please find below the snippet now current time is 6:11 am but if I use DateTime.now() it returns 16:11

Could someone please suggest any workaround except addHours(-10)

[image]

I want to compare dateTime.now() with DateTime.newInstance(date.today(), time.newInstance(20, 0, 0, 0));

I want to compare the current time with 8 pm but when use debug log instead of 8pm I get 6 am

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Salesforce always stores and represents dates internally using GMT, not in the time zone of the current user. Generally, you should not use methods like `addHours()` to alter a DateTime value for one time zone or another; what that does internally is just changes the time, but leaves it in GMT, and this often results in unexpected changes when you go to format the value for display or persist it to the database.

The better approach is to explicitly ask the system to provide you with a formatted, locale-sensitive value. You can call [`DateTime.format()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm) with an optional format string to get a localized, displayable version of the value that's converted into the running user's time zone.

```
System.debug(DateTime.now().format());
```

for example, should yield a formatted result in your time zone.

### Edit

If you want to find out whether it is after 8 pm in the running user's local time zone, you can construct a `DateTime` instance that represents that point in time.

```
public static Datetime newInstance(Date date, Time time)
```

> Constructs a DateTime from the specified date and time in the local time zone.

You'd do

```
DateTime eightPmToday = DateTime.newInstance(Date.today(), Time.newInstance(20, 0, 0, 0));
```

and then compare that value to `DateTime.now()`.

If I run this in an org in Mountain Time (GMT-0600), I can see in the debug logs

> 13:00:11:004 VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT [1]|eightPmToday|"2019-04-04T02:00:00.000Z"

which is in fact the GMT representation of 8 pm on 2019-04-03 in that time zone (2 am the following day). That GMT representation is then comparable to `DateTime.now()`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response but format converts the result to string but I need to do the comparison between two dates, could you please suggest if how I can do the comparison using format

Comment: DateTime.ValueOf() ?

Comment: DateTime.valueOf(DateTime.now().format()); It gives TypeException

Comment: @gs650x Could you please edit your question to be specific about what you are trying to do?

Comment: Updated my question,please check

Comment: My comparison problem solved with addhours()  but still, there must be some other way to get the correct time, if there is then please let me know

Comment: @gs650x I've updated my answer.